# std::string corruption in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I have problems with viewing strings in my debug VS2012 project. For some reason, either the string is not readable at all - VS reports '`<error string not readable>`' - or the first four characters of the strings are always cut. Even so on constant strings. What could cause this?

Comment: Is this debug build or release build?

Comment: Do you mean char* or std::string?

Comment: debug build, and std::string

Comment: There could be many different reasons. Have you tried using a profiler to check for array overflows and other memory violations? Maybe try to create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) to nail down the problem.